# Добавление элемента инфоблока со свойством типа "Список"

Tags: битрикс

Привет! Подскажите как добавить элемент, со множественным свойством "Список"? XML_ID и значение, XML_ID и значение, ... итд? В документации по функции CIBlockElement::Add ничего подобного не нашел

Answer (score 3):

//добавления элемента с установкой для его свойства пары "значение" и "описание"

```
$el = new CIBlockElement;

$PROP = array();
$PROP[id_property] =  Array(
    "n0" => Array(
        "VALUE" => "value",
    ),
    "n1" => Array(
        "VALUE" => "value",
    ),
);

$arLoadProductArray = Array(
  "IBLOCK_SECTION" => false,
  "IBLOCK_ID" => iblock_id,
  "PROPERTY_VALUES" => $PROP,
  "NAME" => "Элемент",
  );

$PRODUCT_ID = id_element;
$res = $el->Update($PRODUCT_ID, $arLoadProductArray);
```